# Error on update quantity of a variant with productVariantUpdate mutation (Shopify)

Tags: php, graphql, shopify

I am trying to run this mutation to update the quantities of a product variant on shopify via graphql . (https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2023-07/mutations/productvariantupdate)

```
    productVariantUpdate(input: $input) {
            productVariant {
                id
                sku
                product {
                    id
                    title
                }
                inventoryQuantity
            }
            userErrors {
                field
                message
            }
        }
}


$input = [
            'id' => "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/123456",
            'inventoryQuantities' => [
                "availableQuantity" => 123,
                "locationId"        => "gid://shopify/Location/123456789"
            ]
        ];
```

In the answer I am told that it was successful but then when I go to the dashboard I see that the product quantities have not updated .

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try formatting your data as JSON? That works often.

```
'inventoryQuantities' => [{
  "availableQuantity" => 123,
  "locationId"        => "gid://shopify/Location/123456789"
}]
```

Also, run your query against Shopify using GraphiQL or Insomnia or another tool when you have troubles. It is nice as the errors you're making do show up whereas with PHP as your request response generator it might be hiding that aspect from you depending on how you're using it.